# Precision loss while converting string to float or double

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I'm facing this problem:

```
$val = "13.0074809789657";
echo "$val"."<br>";
echo "number_format(\$val, 16,'.',''):" . number_format($val, 16,'.','');
echo "<br>";
echo "number_format(\$val):" . number_format($val);
echo "<br>";
echo "floatval(\$val):" . floatval($val);
echo "<br>";
echo "doubleval(\$val):" . doubleval($val);
```

This code prints the following:

```
13.0074809789657
number_format($val, 16,'.',''):13.0074809789657007 //-->why adding trailing 007? This changes from time to time
number_format($val):13
floatval($val):13.007480979 //--> precision loss here: where are the other trailing decimals?
doubleval($val):13.007480979 //--> precision loss here: where are the other trailing decimals?
```

Since I need to store val in a MySQL db (in a column defined as `DECIMAL (32, 16)`), I need a way to exactly get `13.0074809789657` with all the decimals or a way to add trailing 0's and don't know how.

Comment: I suggest you have a read of [the Wikipedia article on floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) particularly the section on [Accuracy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: you requested 16 decimals, but your provided number only has 13, so PHP filled in the extra 3 with the closest actual-float representation of your string. treat floats the same as the Borg. "We are Float of Borg. Accuracy is irrelevant. You will be approximated".

Comment: it is decided in php.ini ->
; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
; http://php.net/precision
precision = 14

Comment: Ok, then it's better for me to use them as a string maybe, since I use them for comparison purposes?